# Como mudar os botões do form (minimizar, maximizar e fechar)

Tags: delphi, icons, delphi-2010

Tenho um projeto em *Delphi 2010* no qual gostaria de mudar os ícones dos botões **Minimize**, **Maximize**, **Close** que estão representados na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os ícones que eu pretendo utilizar foram criados por mim, logo não pretendo alterar por opções que já venham com o *Delphi*, existe alguma forma de o fazer, para alem da criação de um `Panel` no `Form` com `align to top` com os botões e passando o `BorderStyle to bsNone`?

Se alguém conseguir contribuir com alguma coisa agradeço.

Comment: Procura por skins em delphi :)

Comment: Seu botão é um TBitBtn ? Se for basta você colocar a imagem na propriedade `Glyph`.

Comment: os botões em questão são os do form

Comment: Não tenho certeza se é introduzido no Delphi 2010, mas no XE você pode customizador um estilo, inclusive os botões do *form*, veja: http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/customizing-and-creating-vcl-styles-671

Comment: Aa, entendi sua pergunta. Esse exemplo do @stderr funciona. Já precisei fazer isso uma vez.

Comment: @stderr Não esta disponível esse tipo de configuração para o delphi 2010, alguma sugestão mais?

Comment: @KaranPereira o que pretende dizer com isso pode ser mais explicito?

Comment: dá uma olhada na pasta de instalação do seu Delphi, dentro da pasta bin, deve ter um executável chamado BitmapStyleDesigner.exe

Comment: @VictorZanella sabe-me dizer onde posso encontrar este ficheiro designide230.bpl, quando executo o BitmapStyleDesigner.exe ele diz ter esse ficheiro em falta

Comment: Estranho, as bpls 23 são do Delphi 10 Seattle. E você disse que tem a versão 2010 instalada.

Comment: já tive as duas versões no pc pode ter sido isso que lixou o .exe vou ver se arranjo forma de o executar

Comment: Por favor, não vandalize seus posts. É inadequado porque significa que os futuros leitores não obterão ajuda das respostas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso não consiga editar o Style usando o `BitmapStyleDesigner`, existe uma forma *(Arranjo Técnico)* de fazer.

Você deve adicionar um `TPanel` com `Height` de +/- 32 (fica a seu critério) com `Align = alTop`.

Nesse Panel você vai adicionar os botões que deseja *(Recomendo TSpeedButton)* com `Align = alRight`, colocando os botões sempre arranjados no Right se ocultar algum ou redimensionar a janela eles vão automaticamente se alinha, semelhante aos originais.

Agora defina o `BordeStyle` do Formulário como `bsNone`.

Para o botão fechar use o `Close`

Para o Botão Minimizar use o `Application.Minimize`

Para o Restaura/Minimizar:

```
  if (Nome_Form.WindowState = wsMaximized) then
  begin
    Nome_Form.WindowState := wsNormal;
    {altere a imagem do botão aqui para a que desejar}
  end
  else
  begin
    Nome_Form.WindowState := wsMaximized;
    {altere a imagem do botão aqui para a que desejar}
  end;
```

Agora basta adicionar os botões adicionais que você deseja,

Trabalhoso, mas se for a última opção você notara que o resultado é TOP.

**Edit 01: Movendo o Formulário:**

No Evento OnMouseDown do Panel (que agora é sua barra de Título):

```
begin
  if (Button = mbLeft) then
  begin
    ReleaseCapture;
    Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND,$F012,0);
  end;
```

**Edit 02: Redimensionando o Formulário:**

Declare no Private: `procedure WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;`

```
procedure Nome_Form.WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest);
var
  ScreenPt: TPoint;
begin
  //inherited;
  ScreenPt := ScreenToClient(Point(Msg.Xpos, Msg.Ypos));
  if (ScreenPt.x < 5) then
    Msg.Result := HTLEFT
    // top side
  else if (ScreenPt.y < 5) then
    Msg.Result := HTTOP
    // right side
  else if (ScreenPt.x >= Width - 5) then
    Msg.Result := HTRIGHT
    // bottom side
  else if (ScreenPt.y >= Height - 5) then
    Msg.Result := HTBOTTOM
    // top left corner
  else if (ScreenPt.x < 5) and (ScreenPt.y < 5) then
    Msg.Result := HTTOPLEFT
    // bottom left corner
  else if (ScreenPt.x < 5) and (ScreenPt.y >= Height - 5) then
    Msg.Result := HTBOTTOMLEFT
    // top right corner
  else if (ScreenPt.x >= Width - 5) and (ScreenPt.y < 5) then
    Msg.Result := HTTOPRIGHT
    // bottom right corner
  else if (ScreenPt.x >= Width - 5) and (ScreenPt.y >= Height - 5) then
    Msg.Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT
end;
```

Obs: A Declaração do procedimento que redimensiona deve ser assim mesmo, diferente do corpo do procedimento, funciona como se estivesse enviando um `SendMessage` para a **Api** do Windows!

Dessa forma ate o Cursor do Mouse vai mudar de forma ao se aproximar da borda do formulário!

**Edit 03: Container Novo**

Agora como o Formulário não possui borda, precisamos criar um novo Container para os componentes que precisam ser alinhados usando o por exemplo o alCliente, alLeft etc...

No `OnResize` do Formulário:

```
  Panel_Principal.Left   := 5;
  Panel_Principal.Top    := 5; {observar o outro panel que é a barra de Título}
  Panel_Principal.Width  := Nome_Form.Width - 10;
  Panel_Principal.Height := Nome_Form.Height - 10;
```

Dessa forma o Panel_Principal e o Formulário criara o efeito da borda.

Importante: Para não ter essa trabalheira toda em todos os forms, você deve usar este como um Modelo e os demais usar como Herança. Porém, para cada novo form no `OnResize` você devera programar novamente o mesmo `OnResize`.

Comment: Nesse caso, como ficaria a questão de mover o form ? Seria necessário mexer na aparência do botão também para não ficar aquelas bordas arredondadas do SpeedButton ? Como habilitar o redimensionamento do form ? São opções que perdemos ao marcar o form como `bsNone`. Acredito que a ideia é válida, mas teria muito mais trabalho do que apenas incluir os botões.

Comment: O SpeedButton possui a propriedade Flat, Habilitou ele fica Liso! Sobre Mover o form já estou editando para adicionar, quando ao redimensionar tenho em casa o código pronto! Chegar lá eu coloco aqui. O ideal seria fazer essas mudanças em um form e usa-lo como Herança, assim os demais já fica com o mesmo padrão, só precisa fazer uma única vez!

Comment: Legal, estarei aguardando. Já pensou em disponibilizar uma lib para isso ?

Comment: @JúniorMoreira obrigado pela dica mas tal como mencionado pelo Victor, ao fazer dessa forma vou perder muitas opções as quais me iriam ser muito úteis, se conseguir completar então o código agradecia

Comment: Sim, a parte de redimensionar quando chegar em casa faço essa edição. Mover o Form já esta na resposta!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira aguardarei então por nova edição da resposta

Comment: @JúniorMoreira funcionou tudo perfeito, apesar de não ser o que eu queria, gostaria de obter outra resposta, mas agradeço o esforço e uma vez mais obrigado

Comment: Tranquilo, aparecendo alguma novidade Atualizamos aqui!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira estou com um strees o redimensionar não funciona nas zonas em que tenho componentes alinhados as "bordas" do form alguma solução para isso? já agora e possível de o form ficar com bordas visíveis? alem disso tudo ainda tenho outra questão e possível fazer um form desta forma e guardar, depois iniciar um novo projecto e em vez do form do delphi eu alterar o guardado por este?